# Getting error while implement facebook ads

Tags: android, facebook

Failed to find provider info for `com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider`

When I install Facebook app then this error is not occur, but another error occur:

```
E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5ced1368 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x5e928a18 arg=0x0
E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5ced1368 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA
```

and my ads is not shown..

Can you help me?

Comment: have you added INTERNET permission ?

Comment: yes i added permission